# React Memory Leakage with typescript using google firestore and react router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am currently using firestore but I am currently getting problems with memory leakage as I delete transactionally delete my component just before I leave the screen what is the best way I to avoid this leakage When I click on the link component I want to remove the notification from the database it seems to work and take me to the new page the only problem is that I get a memory leak how should I avoid this.

```
const loadAlerts = useCallback(() => {
        const alertNotifcationsObserver = onSnapshot(notifications, (querySnapshot) => {
            const alertData: any[] = []
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.data())
                alertData.push({
                    ...doc.data(),
                    doc

                })
            });
            setAlertNotifcations(alertData)
        });
        return alertNotifcationsObserver
    }, [notifications])


    useEffect(() => {
        loadAlerts();
        console.log(alertNotifications)
    }, []);
```

```
  <IonItem onClick={async (e) => {
                                            console.log(i.Reference)
                                          await  notificationsController(i.Reference)
                                        }} key={i.Reference} lines='full'>
                                                <Link
                                                    to={{
                                                        pathname: i.Link,
                                                        state: { documentReferencePath: i.Reference }
                                                    }}
                                                >
                                                    {i.Type}
                                                </Link>
                                        </IonItem>
```

```
const notificationsController = async(documentReferencePath:string)=>{

 
    try {
        await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
          const documentReference =  doc(db,documentReferencePath)
          const notificationDoc = await transaction.get(documentReference);
          if (!notificationDoc.exists()) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
          }
          transaction.delete(documentReference)
        });
        console.log("Notification removed successfully committed!");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
      }
```

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

How do I get rid of this error  also I tried to add unsubscribe for loadAlerts but type script gives me a error too.

```
Argument of type '() => () => Unsubscribe' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems unlikely you'll call the `loadAlerts` function outside the `useEffect` hook or in any other callback, move it into the `useEffect` hook to remove it as a dependency, and return a cleanup function from the `useEffect` to unsubscribe.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    notifications,
    (querySnapshot) => {
      const alertData: any[];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        alertData.push({
          ...doc.data(),
          doc,
        });
      });
      setAlertNotifcations(alertData);
    });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped  just wanted to add that .map is not a function of a  a querysnapshot<documentData>